# Can I transfer full IIS config and settings from a bad non-booting drive to a new drive

Tags: iis

Background ; A Boot drive has crashed from a power failure. All data is intact but it will not boot. Tried pretty much everything to fix the boot problem which is a Blue screen after listing all drivers from Safe Mode.

Issue ; On this drive a an IIS setup with a lot of databases and users etc etc. Cannot run a backup/export of course because I cannot boot from that drive.

Apart from just copying `C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config` across which doesn't really work (HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable.) is there any way to recover fully to the new drive ?

Thanks

Comment: Did the 503 appear after starting the app pool?

Comment: are you sure you mean IIS not SQLServer? IIS doesn't store databases or users.

Comment: Thanks @FrankThomas yes quite right my mistake please ignore reference to users  :)

Comment: Thanks @spikey_richie From what I can tell all app pools are running as they appear in the Application Pools list as status Started. I have around 14 pools altogether one of which is called DefaultAppPool and that one handles about 57 domains. Irrespective of what site I try and load, the 503 appears for that site. Moreover I created a new pool and attached that to an existing site and still get the 503 for that one as well.

Comment: Just looked at the httperr log file and see the following, which is consistent for all sites I have tried. AppOffline being the operative word ; 
2021-05-25 01:28:22 ::1%0 50923 ::1%0 80 HTTP/1.1 GET /A1 503 1 AppOffline ZimZam
2021-05-25 01:28:22 ::1%0 50924 ::1%0 80 HTTP/1.1 GET /favicon.ico 503 1 AppOffline DefaultAppPool

Comment: Another update - I had create a new application pool called ZimZam. Attached that to a site called A1. The pool starts fine. However when I try and run the site A1, the app pool stops, presumably unloaded due to whatever is causing the fundamental problem. By the way if I try and Browse the site from IIS I also get the 503.

Comment: There are many possible reasons why this cannot work, so it is impossible to give a complete answer to this question. Consider asking (or looking for) more specific questions for each problem you run into.

Comment: One problem could be the application pool identity. If you set a password, then it is encrypted with a machine key in applicationHost.config and cannot be decrypted on another machine. To solve this, either create a new application pool, or set the application pool identity again.